decoded json list string not there
can amyone can help me with a decoded json list?
In the blocks below when the list is shorter I get error.
enter image description here
What is the best option to put a default text if missing?
Thank you!
I try with procedures and to check the lenght of list but they are created at runtime and I cant figure out a solution
